# Can't resolve all parameters for UIRouter: (?, ?)

Tags: angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

I am using angular2 and uirouter for routing. I have successfully implemented uirouter module in application.But the problem arises when i try to test my application. Where i am using karma, Jasmin and initiating it using `npm test`. but encountered with `ERROR:Can't resolve all parameters for UIRouter: (?, ?).`

I have imported "UIRouter" in `*.spec.ts` file and added it in providers array as below.

```
import { UIRouterModule } from '@uirouter/angular';
import { UIRouter } from "@uirouter/core";
describe('Footer Menus', () => {
  let footerMenuBlServiceRef:FooterMenuBLService;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [],
      providers: [UIRouter],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

But no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it !!!
Just remove the `UIRouter` from `providers` array but keep the import statement for it. and yes its working.

Comment: Hi shiv! Could you give more details about you resolution please?
I am having the same issue and your answer did not help me to solve mine.

I have UIRouterModule.forChild in my module and I don't know how to mock it in the spec file. Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Hey Pitchou, would you please add your spec file code for better clarity of   your problem. I only need your imports and  beforeEach functions data.

Answer (score 1):

On last friday, I finally found a way to make it work. It is not a clean way to do it but it is working, at least.

I reimport the UIRouter.forRoot with the states of my feature module and I provide the APP_BASE_HREF value for the Root Provider of UIRouter.

Here is my BeforeEach :

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            HomeComponent,
            HomeCardComponent
        ],
        imports: [
            AppMaterialModule,
            // Always import root UIRouter module when testing a component including routing
            UIRouterModule.forRoot({states: HOME_STATES})
        ],
        providers: [
            // Also, include the base href value when testing a component including routing
            {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
        ],
    }).compileComponents();
}));
```

If you know a better way, I would be happy to know! :)

Answer (score 0):

The UI-Router [source](https://github.com/ui-router/angular/blob/master/test/uiSref/uiSref.spec.ts#L53) can be of some help. This is what worked for me:

```
import { UIRouterModule } from '@uirouter/angular';
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    ...
    imports: [UIRouterModule.forRoot({ useHash: true })],
})
```